# Windows forms lost focus when two consecutive MessageBox pop are fired

Tags: c#, forms, winforms, messagebox

```
Class MainForm:Form {
    Public CheckValidation()
    {
    var controller = new FormController();
    controller.checkValidation();
    }
}

    class FormController {
    public checkValidation ()
{
    MessageBox.Show('test_a',MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxDefaultButton.Button1, MessageBoxOptions.ServiceNotification);
    MessageBox.Show('test_b',MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxDefaultButton.Button1, MessageBoxOptions.ServiceNotification);
    }
}
```

**The problem** is that after the first message box pop-up box closes, the focus is lost to some other application on windows such as outlook.

**The expectation** is that the focus is sent to the second message box pop up, which is queued to be executed next. So that I don't have to manually click on the second pop-up box to make it active to close it. And after the second pop-up box closes the focus return to the main form.

Comment: This will not be easy to control.  Windows keeps getting worse about focus issues.  You could try anchoring the MessageBox by setting the first parameter to `this`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Solution:**
Removing the `'MessageBoxOptions.ServiceNotification'` parameter worked.

**Alternative Solution 1:**

If we wish to explicitly specify that the message box should always be in the front and top most window, we can specify parameter ((0x40000) which is flag for MB_TOPMOST option.

```
MessageBox.Show('test_a', MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxDefaultButton.Button1, (MessageBoxOptions)0x40000); //Message Box Top Most (MB_TOPMOST) = 0x40000
```

**Alternative Solution 2:**
Another way to explicitly specify that the message box should always be in the front and top most window, we can create a new form object and set the ‘TopMost’ Boolean option to ‘True’.

```
MessageBox.Show(new Form() { TopMost = true }, 'test_b', MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxDefaultButton.Button1);
```